# SCSS - How to loop nested maps within map-merge?

Tags: css, sass

I have a nicely working SCSS function with which I can call any color like so:

```
color: clr(milk);
```

Now I would like to make some kind of loop within the map-merge so that when, for example I add a new nested map called 'tertiary' with some other colors, the colors automatically become available without having to add

```
map-get(colors, 'tertiary')
```

to the map-merge. Does anyone know how to do this? Below is my current function:

```
$colors: (
    primary: (
        milk: #fff,
        cola: #000,
        mine-shaft: #232323,
    ),
    secondary: (
        pampas: #f4f1ef,
        pearl-brush: #e9e2dd,
        alto: #ddd,
    ),
);

// Color generation
@function clr($color) {
    $color: map-get(map-merge(map-get($colors, 'primary'), map-get($colors, 'secondary')), $color);

    @return $color;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice project! `map-merge()` can be indeed used to achieve what you want, however it adds an unnecessary step. I'd recommend to simply use a nested loop coupled with an `@if` statement.

```
@function clr($find) {
  @each $colorCategoryName, $colorCategory in $colors {
    @each $colorName, $color in $colorCategory {
      @if $find == $colorName {
        @return $color;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**For example:** This...

```
$colors: (
  "primary": (
    "milk":       #fff,
    "cola":       #000,
    "mine-shaft": #232323,
  ),
  "secondary": (
    "pampas":      #f4f1ef,
    "pearl-brush": #e9e2dd,
    "alto":        #ddd,
  ),
);

@function clr($find) {
  @each $colorCategoryName, $colorCategory in $colors {
    @each $colorName, $color in $colorCategory {
      @if $find == $colorName {
        @return $color;
      }
    }
  }
}

body {
  color: clr(cola);
  background-color: clr(pampas);
}
```

**Will output:**

```
body {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #f4f1ef;
}
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!